# what does the set $0 < x_{1} < x_{2} < 1 $ mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do I interpret the set  $  S = \{ (x_{1}, x_{2}) \space \big| \space 0 < x_{1} < x_{2} < 1 \} $ ? How do I plot the set on a $2$ dimensional graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is just $any$ two real numbers $x_1,x_2 \in (0,1)$ such that $x_1 < x_2$ for example ,$x_1 = 0.5,x_2 = 0.6$ is a possibility

other possibilities $$(x_1,x_2) = (0.1,0.2),$$

$$(x_1,x_2) = (0.2,0.3) $$

$$(x_1,x_2)= (0.35,0,45)$$

keep in mind, there are infinite possibilities because we are dealing with the reals.

the set can be represented as a dotted triangle, the unit square with the diagonal from the origin $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$  assuming that $x_1 = x$ and $x_2 = y$ in a $x-y$ graph fashion where $x$ is the horizontal axis and $y$ is the vertical axis

here is a link to the plot [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%20%3C%20x%20%3C%20y%20%3C%201)

Comment: The "plot" would be a triangle, the unit square with the diagonal from the origin to (1,1) cut, and only the lower portion taken. Note, this is an open set.

Comment: @JoeMoeller yes you are right